# How is a primitive procedure tagged in SICP's evaluator (chapter 4)?

Tags: eval, apply, procedure, primitive, sicp

I am reading chapter 4 of SICP. In the `eval` procedure, there is a procedure `application`. This procedure checks whether the expression is tagged with the symbol `'primitive` or `'procedure`.

I can see where the symbol `'procedure` is added. (It is when evaluating a lambda expression.).

I am not able to find where the tag `'primitive` is added? Clearly, when I supply a program to the evaluator, I supply `(+ 1 2)` and not `('primitive + 1 2)`. I would guess the `'primitive` tag is added somewhere (like `'procedure`), but I cannot find where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `primitive-procedure-objects` procedure, that's where the `'primitive` tag is added to the elements of the `primitive-procedures` list, which contains the primitive operations available to the interpreter.

In turn, `primitive-procedure-objects` is called inside `setup-environment`, which is used for creating the initial environment for the interpreter.

When evaluating an expression such as `(+ 1 2)`, the evaluator simply goes all the way down in the case analysis of `eval`, matching the `application?` predicate, which invokes `apply` and then `(eval (operator exp) env)` on the first element of the expression. In turn, this matches `variable?` in the case analysis, which calls `lookup-variable-value`, that returns a procedure, which we tagged with `'primitive` in `setup-environment`. Whew!

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. But, how is it "reached" from `eval`. I mean, if I supply `(+ 1 2)` to the evaluator, how does it end up being seen as a `primitive-procedure?` if there is no `'primitive` tag in what I supplied to the evaluator?

Comment: @Gradient there you go :)

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thank you!